# Использование методов fit_transform и transform

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, kaggle

Прохожу тренинг на *kaggle* по машинному обучению и столкнулся с недопониманием. Есть код:

```
# Make copy to avoid changing original data (when imputing)
X_train_plus = X_train.copy()
X_valid_plus = X_valid.copy()

# Make new columns indicating what will be imputed
for col in cols_with_missing:
    X_train_plus[col + '_was_missing'] = X_train_plus[col].isnull()
    X_valid_plus[col + '_was_missing'] = X_valid_plus[col].isnull()

# Imputation
my_imputer = SimpleImputer()
imputed_X_train_plus = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.fit_transform(X_train_plus))
imputed_X_valid_plus = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.transform(X_valid_plus))

# Imputation removed column names; put them back
imputed_X_train_plus.columns = X_train_plus.columns
imputed_X_valid_plus.columns = X_valid_plus.columns

print("MAE from Approach 3 (An Extension to Imputation):")
print(score_dataset(imputed_X_train_plus, imputed_X_valid_plus, y_train, y_valid))
```

Функция `score_dataset()` возвращает среднюю абсолютную ошибку.

**Вопрос**: Почему для данных обучения мы используем метод `fit_transform()`, а для тестовых данных просто `transform()`?

`fit_transform()` сначала вызывает метод `fit` потом `transform`, кого мы обучаем в этом случае? мы же просто создаем датафрейм.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По данным обучения (у вас - X_train_plus) вы обучаете свою модель. В данном случае - вы хотите научиться заполнять пропущенные значения. fit_transform() это и делает. При этом результат модели, которую он использовал для заполнения он сохранил во внутренних параметрах  вашего объекта my_imputer.

По данным валидации (у вас - X_valid_plus) вам уже ничего обучать не надо. Вам надо их только заполнить, используя при этом те самые запомненные ранее параметры объекта my_imputer.

Answer (score 4):

Если вдруг этот вопрос ещё для кого-то актуален, хотел бы дополнить ответ уважаемого **passant**.

> **Вопрос:** Почему для данных обучения мы используем метод
> `fit_transform()`, а для тестовых данных просто `transform()`?

По-хорошему такой методики нужно придерживаться всегда. Обучение любых моделей, включая такие прострые штуки как скейлеры, импутеры, нужно проводить исключительно на тренировочных данных. Модель не должна видеть тестовой и валидационной части данных на этапе обучения. Даже если речь о заполнении пропусков или масштабировании. Любое нарушение этого правила рано или поздно закончится "утечкой данных", в результате чего модель будет показывать на тестовой/валидационной части данных результаты лучше, чем они есть на самом деле.

Ну и кроме того, как уже было упомянуто, даже скейлеры и импутеры обучаются. Скейлер может запомнить минимум и максимум значений каждой фичи, импутер может запомнить, например, медианы фич. Поэтому на тренировочных данных делаем `fit_transform` - одновременно и обучаемся и преобразуем тренировочные данные. А на тестовых/валидационных данных делаем уже только `transform` - преобразуем данные согласно ранее запомненным параметрам, полученным на тренировочной выборке.